# Federation Issue

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-8

I have couple of questions in federation process.

1) Can a node of **WAS V8.5.5** be federated into the DMGR of **WAS V7.0** ?

2) Can a node running on **Windows7 O/S** federated into the **DMGR sitting in

        linux O/S** **(Linux O/S is running in VMWare in the same machine as Windows)**?

I was trying the federation process in different scenarios. I tried to federate a **node of WAS V8.5.5** running on Windows 7 with **dmgr of WAS V7.0** running on linux O/S (linux is running on VMWare in the same machine as Windows) and got an error while federating. Tried from the DMGR console as well as the command prompt of node V8.5.5.
Both the DMGR and the server are running and also checked the host names. Both the host names are different.

The error is...

**com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx at port xxxx.**

Can any one please suggest whether I can try the above scenario? If so what might be causing to get the error?

Answer (score 0):

***1) Can a node of WAS V8.5.5 be federated into the DMGR of WAS V7.0 ?***

No, the DMGR must be on highest version/fixpack level. So you will have to upgrade DMGR from version 7 to version 8.5.5 to be able to federate 8.5.5 nodes. Howerver upgraded DMGR can still manage v7 nodes. See [Overview of migration, coexistence, and interoperability](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.migration.nd.doc/ae/cmig_overview.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-4-0-0-0&lang=en)

***2) Can a node running on Windows7 O/S federated into the DMGR sitting in
linux O/S (Linux O/S is running in VMWare in the same machine as Windows)?***

Yes, as long as DMGR is on the same or higher version and there is connectivity between host and guest (verify your firewall settings in both - host and guest, you may need to modify `/etc/hosts` files to add ip hostname mappings).

Comment: Hi Gas, I did find the hosts file in etc directory (both in Linux and Windows) could you please give the absolute path where the hosts file reside? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ronu On Linux systems it is in `/etc/hosts`, on Windows it is `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`

Comment: Hi Gas, I did not find the hosts file in etc directory (both in Linux and Windows) could you please give the absolute path where the hosts file reside? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Gas, Thanks for you response.  Dmgr is running in Linux O/S and other nodes in Windows 7 O/S. How can I map ip mappings in both O/S' hosts file. Please advice.

Comment: @ronu You just write Ip and host name in both files, like: `x.x.x.x dmgrhostName`, new line, `y.y.y.y nodeHostName`